# Image on top of another one in Beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, floats, overlays

I am trying to place an image on top of another in beamer.
I am using

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\mode<presentation>
%frame
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
     \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme[watermark=ntua-logo.jpg]{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title[July 2012 H4 Test Beam\hspace{3cm} Stony Brook, NYC]{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]            {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
calc,%
fadings,%
shadings%
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{paralist}

 \begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%\uncover<1->{\begin{figure}
%  \begin{center}
%    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{layers1}
%  \end{center} 
%\end{figure}}
%\hspace{-15cm}
%\uncover<2->{
%\begin{figure}
%  \begin{center}
%    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{layers}
%  \end{center} 
%\end{figure}}
\hspace{-15cm}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \uncover<1->{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{layers1}}%
    \llap{\raisebox{0cm}{%  move next graphics to top right corner
     \uncover<2->{ \includegraphics[width=10cm]{layers}}%
    }}
%    \caption{My overlay figure.}
  \end{figure}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also tried using just the `figure` enviroment with `\hspace{}` between two images but it didn't work.{Code in comment}

Comment: To clarify: by "on top of", you mean "above" rather than "superimposed on", right?

Comment: I mean `superimposed` indeed! Please see `uncover`. The plan is to have the first image and then at the exact same position the socond one.

Comment: Sometimes the problem is in the graphics file. For example, the bounding box may be wrong. Have you tried something along the following lines (compile twice)? `\documentclass{beamer} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} \begin{frame}[fragile] \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] \only<1>{\draw (current page.center) node[anchor=center] {stuff};} \only<2>{\draw (current page.center) node[anchor=center] {more stuff};} \end{tikzpicture} \end{frame} \end{document}`

Comment: I used your code and it is working. I can tell the difference now. You are right!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not use the `figure` environment, it makes no real sense in beamer

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphics}%% Delete it later
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Titel}{Subtitle}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.35\textheight]{foo}
\captionof{figure}{first image}
\includegraphics[height=0.35\textheight]{bar}
\captionof{figure}{second image}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and here the same as an overlay (on top of each other)

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphics}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Titel}{Subtitle}
\centering
\only<1>{\includegraphics[height=0.7\textheight]{foo}
\captionof{figure}{first image}}
\only<2>{\includegraphics[height=0.7\textheight]{bar}
\captionof{figure}{second image}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't mean that... I want them to be superimposed...Sorry for the inconvinience!

Comment: see edit, the second example

Comment: If the images are not the same size, you will need to use an `overlayarea1 to avoid the rest of the content 'jumping around'.

Comment: @Joseph: not when I controll the height of the image instead of the width

Comment: @Herbert Yes, I realise that in your demo. In the 'real' case though the images might not scale up so well, or might want to be displayed at the same scale as each other (I do that a lot for chemical structures). Not a criticism of the answer: just an additional point that the OP might need to know.

Comment: I saw you edit-sorry. The thing is that despite `centering`,  image is not centered...

Comment: @Thanos: take my example, then delete the first line and insert your image. If it is not centered then you have some whitespace around your image. If you could provide the sources of your images then we can have a look, too.

Comment: I used `center` enviroment and it is working! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Thanos: the `center` environment adds some vertical white space before and after. And this is especially in the limited height of a slide not a good option. `\centering` doesn't

Comment: Actually I copied only the `frame` code... But it OK!!!